# How to do Redis (redigo) lpop in golang

Tags: go, redis

I need to do a simple lpop from a redis queue. 
In go lang If I use a blocking pop using blpop then the foll code works

```
reply, err := redis.Strings(conn.Do("BLPOP", key, 1))
        if err == nil {         
           fmt.Println(reply[1])

        // do something with string reply[1]

       }
```

But I do not want to block. I just need to end when the queue is empty. 
So how can I do that 
If I do `redis.Strings(conn.Do("LPOP", key))`
ie change BLPOP to LPOP and I get a redigo error

```
ERROR = redigo: unexpected type for Strings, got type []uint8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can get the lpop'ed value using redis.String()

so this works

```
reply, err := redis.String(conn.Do("LPOP", key))
    if err == nil { 
     fmt.Printf("REPLY= %s\n", reply)
      //do something
```

Answer (score 0):

The [BLPOP](https://redis.io/commands/blpop) command returns a two element array where the first element is the key and the second value is the popped element.

The [LPOP](https://redis.io/commands/lpop) command returns the popped element.

Use the String helper function to get the popped element:

```
reply, err := redis.String(conn.Do("LPOP", key))
        if err == nil {         
           fmt.Println(reply)
        // do something with string reply
       }
```

Comment: Does not work 
LPOP does not take a timeout option 
I get this error 

ERROR = ERR wrong number of arguments for 'lpop' command

Also if I were to pass only 2 args still that does not give me a string output

Comment: Sorry, that was a copy and paste error with the extra argument to LPOP.  Fixed.  The key point is that you should use redis.String when for commands that return a single value.